# flutter - firebase - query check if two fields are not empty

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my app, I must check if two fields are not empty.

it seems that it is not possible. So, I have done the code below.

I am getting this error: Unhandled Exception: 'package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart': Failed assertion: line 313 pos 7: 'field is String || field is FieldPath || field == FieldPath.documentId': Supported [field] types are [String] and [FieldPath].

I must make sure that I have not fields empty because it will generate an error because I am parsing the text. Thank you.

```
myQueryResult.where('start_Date', isNotEqualTo: '');

myQueryResult = myQueryResult.where('due_Date'.length, isEqualTo : 16);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation on [Firestore query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations):

> In a compound query, range (`<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`) and not equals (`!=`, `not-in`) comparisons must all filter on the same field.

So you can't check non-equality on two different fields. You'll either have to perform one of the conditions in the query, and the other in your application code (which **reads** more data than needed), or you will have to introduce an additional field in your document that combines the two things you want to check for in a single value that you can then query on (which **stores** additional data to prevent reading more than needed).

Comment: Thank you. I will introduce an additional field.